# Question about a set of vectors spanning a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\operatorname{span} \{(1, -3, 2), (2, -4, -1), (1, -5, 7)\} = \{(x, y, z): 11x + 5y + 2z = 0\}$. None of the vectors are the scalar multiples of each other. Shouldn't they span the whole of $\mathbb R^3$, not just a plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Note that $3(1,-3,2)-(1,-5,7)=(2,-4,-1)$. Then, the vectors aren't linearly independent.

Comment: Ah, ok. One more question: if a set of vectors spans a plane, can we always define the property of span in terms of dot product? In the given example $11x + 5y + 2z = (11, 5, 2) \cdot (x, y, z) = 0$.

Comment: Of course. Every plane passing trought (0,0,0) can be expressed as $ax+by+cz=0$, which is $(a,b,c)\cdot(x,y,z)$, giving us that a normal vector to the plane is $(a,b,c)$.